# Is there a way to alias "redirect stdout and stderr to a file"?

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

## [Relevant Context](https://linuxize.com/post/bash-redirect-stderr-stdout/):

#### Redirect standard out

```bash
command > file
```

```bash
command 1> file
```

#### Redirect standard error

```bash
command 2> file
```

#### Redirect standard out and standard error to separate files

```bash
command 2> error.txt 1> output.txt
```

#### Redirect standard out and standard error to the same file

```bash
command > file 2>&1
```

```bash
command &> file # bash only? 
# For all I know, all the examples are bash-only, but the article called it out explicitly on this line
```

Warning: the following example redirects *only* stdout to file. This happens because the stderr is redirected to stdout before the stdout was redirected to file

```bash
command 2>&1 > file # incorrect!
```

## Question:

In my mind, these symbols are completely arbitrary, and therefore, difficult to memorize. I know how to alias *commands*, but is there some way to alias these symbols to make them easier to remember? Something like this:

#### Redirect standard out and standard error to the same file

```bash
command redirectStandardOutputAndError file
```

or even better:

```bash
command >outerr file
```

Bonus points if this works on zsh and bash, but I'm bash is the only requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use aliases to do this in bash, they just are not powerful enough. However you can use functions, which might help you.

This approach does require you to think about redirection a little differently. You state the redirection first, and then the command, so if you want to save the output of `ls -l` in `/tmp/dir_listing` you would type `save_in /tmp/dir_listing ls -l`

```
save_in(){ # save stdout in file
    "${@:2}" > "$1"
}

save_all(){ # save both stdout and stderr in file
     "${@:2}" > "$1" 2>&1
}

save_each(){ # save stdout and stderr in different files
     "${@:3}" > "$1" 2>"$2"
}

save_base(){ # save stdout and stderr into different file, just give base
    "${@:2}" > "$1.out" 2>"$1.err"
}
```

The difficulty is coming up with reasonable names that are memorable.

Comment: Re "not powerful enough": zsh does have a feature called global aliases which have this funtionality: `alias -g OUTERR='&>'; ls -l OUTERR file` works.

Comment: @corvus_192 ooh, I may use that. I assumed bash's `&>` symbol would be different in zsh.